# Unable to add NuGet Package to Solution for Dynamics 365

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am trying to add the CoreAssemblies package to the solution. When trying to add it to framework version 4.5.2 or 4.6.1 (the two frameworks available below 4.7.2), it is throwing me an error: "the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework." On the website nuget.org say .net 4.6.2 is now required as a baseline. So, I am forced to work on 4.7.2. When I tried to register my dll file on 4.7.2, I have an error which says required framework should be below 4.7.1.

Can someone help me with this, please.

Comment: What's wrong with targeting 4.6.2?

Answer (score 0):

You can just download the 4.6.2 https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net462

After that you should be able to build your Project with 4.6.2